# Android: How to pass an object from a simple class to an Activity

Tags: android, parsing, class, object, android-activity

I have the following problem. 
I have a class named "A" in which I create a list "List dStruct" . 
I modify this object in the "A" class and I want to pass it to an Activity for further use.

Also the "A" class extends AsyncTask.

In this case,how do I pass an object to an Activity?

Here is the Activity Code:

List  dStruct; //the object I want to access

btnPlanTrip.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

```
     tripReq = new TripRequest(MainActivity.this);
     tripReq.execute(request);
     dStruct=tripReq.dStruct;


     String str= dStruct.get(0).name;

}
```

Here is the code for the class "A"

`public class TripRequest extends AsyncTask {`

List  dStruct;

```
 public TripRequest(MainActivity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
    dStruct=new ArrayList <DirectionsStruct>();
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
```

}

protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {

```
   code for dStruct 

 }
```

}

Comment: Do you call class "A" from your activity?

Comment: see this [pass a custom data object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6722463/how-to-pass-a-custom-data-object-within-a-intent)

Comment: If I am not mistaken, your proposed method involves passing an object from one activity to another activity. The class "A" does not extend activity but it extends AsyncTask as shown above (I edited the code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue using [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)s. In my custom AsyncTask, I pass a Handler from an Activity to the constructor. In the AsyncTask's `onPostExecute`, I call Handler.sendMessage and it sends whatever data back to the Activity.

AsyncTask Code (your "A" class)

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<RestClient, Void, RestResponse> {
     Handler handler;

    public MyAsyncTask(Handler handler) {
         this.handler = handler;
    }

    @Override
    protected RestResponse doInBackground(RestClient... rc) {
        // Get data from web service or whatever...
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(RestResponse response){
        Message msg = Message.obtain();
        msg.obj = response;
        this.handler.sendMessage(msg);
    }
}
```

Handler declared in Activity

```
private Handler activityHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            // Do something with msg.obj
    };
```

Call to AsyncTask from Activity passing in Handler to ctor (do this in your button click event handler)

```
MyAsyncTask async = new MyAsyncTask(activityHandler);
async.execute(...);
```

Comment: could you give me an example of that? I call the "A" class based on a click event.

Comment: First of all thanks for your quick answer. Secondly, how do I pass the  dStruct into the message? Is it done like this? msg.obj=dStruct. Thirdly, how do I access it through activity? I don't quite understand. Sorry for the inconvenience am causing you but I am quite new to programming

Comment: Yes, pass dStruct as you described: msg.obj = dStruct. In your Activity, you must have a Handler declared that overrides handleMessage (see my code under "Handler declared in Activity"). This where you you retrieve your dStruct from msg.obj.

Answer (score 1):

Arbitrary Java objects aren't really first-class constructs form an Android point of view.

The "main" thread enters your code though an Activity/Broadcast Receiver/Service/Content Provider/View...well, you get the idea. Application code can then control flow as it wishes, spawning new threads, sending intents for the OS to route appropriately, and utilizing other arbitrary classes (like your class A). However, your activity has to ask A, A can't tell your activity.

That being said, if your activity instantiates A, and A creates the List called dStruct in an instance method, you could do something like this.

```
public partial Class A { 
    public List createDStruct(){
        List dStruct = new List()
        //Do stuff to dStruct
        return dStruct
    }

public partial Class MyActivity {
    public List retrieveDstruct(){
        A a = new A()
        return a.createDStruct()
    }
}
```